# Flutter change Scaffold drawer icon

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the default Scaffold drawer icon (hamburger icon).

I tried to add a key to the Scaffold widget and a leading icon, but it didn't work form me:

```
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        /* ... */
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          onPressed: () {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        /* ... */
      ),
      /* ... */
    );
  }
}
```

**How can I change the drawer icon?**

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by adding a leading icon wrapped by a Builder widget (the key was not needed):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    /*...*/
    leading: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
          onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
        );
      },
    ),
   /*...*/
);
```